WinUI 3 NavigationService not navigating to ShellPage after successful login
I'm developing a WinUI 3 app using Template Studio with a Navigation Bar. The INavigationService has a NavigateTo method that I can use to navigate between custom pages like Login and SignUp. However, I'm having an issue where I can't navigate to ShellPage after a successful login.
Specifically, the following code doesn't work as expected:
private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
private UIElement? _shell;

public LoginViewModel(IAuthService authService, INavigationService navigationService)
{
    _authService = authService;
    _navigationService = navigationService;
}

if (loginSuccessful)
{
    // Not working in this context
    _navigationService.NavigateTo(typeof(ShellViewModel).FullName!);

    // Works but doesn't show full content of ShellPage (doesn't automatically activate BlankPage)
    var shell = App.GetService<ShellPage>();
    App.MainWindow.Content = shell ?? (UIElement)new Frame();
}

Interestingly, if I use NavigateTo with custom pages like SignUp, it works fine:
public void NavigateToSignUp()
{
    _navigationService.NavigateTo(typeof(SignUpViewModel).FullName!);
}

I'm try using another way like:
// Works but doesn't show full content of ShellPage (doesn't automatically activate BlankPage)

    var shell = App.GetService<ShellPage>();

    App.MainWindow.Content = shell ?? (UIElement)new Frame();

Then i have got:
enter image description here
But i'm expected:
enter image description here
(The ShellPage included AccountPage)
How can I successfully navigate to ShellPage after login and ensure that ShellPage displays its full content (including automatically activating the default Account)?

The Template Studio has a class called PageService. IIRC, you need to add your navigation targets in its constructor.
For example:
PageService.cs
public PageService()
{
    Configure<MainViewModel, MainPage>();
    Configure<WebViewViewModel, WebViewPage>();
    Configure<ListDetailsViewModel, ListDetailsPage>();
    Configure<ContentGridViewModel, ContentGridPage>();
    Configure<ContentGridDetailViewModel, ContentGridDetailPage>();
    Configure<DataGridViewModel, DataGridPage>();
    Configure<SettingsViewModel, SettingsPage>();

    // Your pages here:
    Configure<ShellViewModel, ShellPage>();
}


It seems that you have solved your issue by yourselfer in the Q&A forum: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2111615/winui-3-navigationservice-not-navigating-to-shellp
if (loginSuccessful)
{
    var shell = App.GetService<ShellPage>();
    App.MainWindow.Content = shell;
    // Get the frame from the shell
    if (shell.FindName("NavigationFrame") is Frame shellFrame)
    {
        _navigationService.Frame = shellFrame;
        _navigationService.NavigateTo(typeof(AccountViewModel).FullName!);
    }
}

